# Mentio JS menu being added to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a Twitter style @mention interface using Angular JS and a library called MentioJS ()

The issue i'm having, is that after content is dynamically added to the page, I'm getting a rogue menu on the bottom of the page. I was able to replicate on the documentation page here:
http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/?#/

By just hitting "Submit" at the bottom without changing anything. In Chrome, I see the default menu that opens in the first input show up again at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue, as many others I think.
I've emptyed the array with the options for mentio-items (after pressing submit), which worked for me.
I`m sure this is not the right solution, but it fullfiels my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with with ment.io, but as @Mihai Lazar pointed out after clearing array on submit, issue was resolved.

Regards..